Relation between published version of RAML in Exchange and API Manager
So I am not quite clear about this .
I have often seen that as we develop HTTP endpoints , we create / modify the raml in Design centre and then publish it to exchange and increment the version
1.0.0
1.0.1 and so on 

However in many of the api of ours what I have seen is that as we publish new versions we do not update the same in API Manager
As an example : In API Manager , Actions ,Change API specifications

here we can see that the version being referred in api manager is not the latest which has been published
am wondering what would be the impact ?

The API deployed in API Manager doesn't has the latest API specification published in Anypoint Exchange.
Exchange is a repository of assets, including API specifications, but doesn't execute anything. Think of it like a catalog. So if you made a change and published it to Exchange, it doesn't impact your deployed API in any way.
If you want to use the latest specification of the API in API Manager you need to change the API specification by selecting the new version.

thanks so lets say I add a new endpoint and publish to exchange as 1.0.4 but in api manager it is still referring to a prior version which does not have this new endpoint , would there be any impact ? and if none why do we even have the option to change the version in api manager ? am trying to understand its relevance in api manager

The API deployed will not know the new endpoint until it is updated.
